# simultaneous opening of php script

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I just met some problem and need direction to solve it.
I have this test script:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$start = microtime(true);
echo 'Start time: '.date('H:i:s')."\n";
sleep(5);
echo 'End time: '.date('H:i:s')."\n";
echo 'Ellapsed time: '.(microtime(true)-$start)."\n";
?>
```

If i run this in Firefox or Chrome in 2 tabs simultaneously i see that script in second tab works only after first script complete its work. In IE9 it works realy simultaneously, not one after another. Where is the problem? Why scripts work not simultaneously in FF and Chrome?

Result for Chrome

1 tab:

```
Start time: 22:34:03
End time: 22:34:08
Ellapsed time: 4.9997730255127
```

2 tab:

```
Start time: 22:34:08
End time: 22:34:13
Ellapsed time: 5.0004279613495
```

Comment: Theres many number of reasons for this, and chances are it all boils down to how each browser renders data being downloaded into itself. But chances are something is working flawlessly in IE and not Chrome or FF then theres something wrong with that concept as IE is usually the one nothing ever works in. My best guess not knowing the inner workings of each browser is. IE starts loading data as soon as the tab function is trigged, where as FF and Chrome likely wait for the tab to be open and ready to download data before downloading.

Comment: So in short IE downloading before the tab is fired off and ready means your script is rendering faster in IE, where as in Chrome and FF your have that moment where the tab is reaching a ready state then begins working hence your delay

Comment: On another note, I don't think you will make your users happy if they land on your page, or click a single link and you have 1 or 2 new windows/tabs open on them, also worth mentioning is that all modern browsers usually have a default state that disallow new windows from popping open if the popup is generated from a script automating the process.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Original problem is that my web app send 2 simulteniously ajax requests to different or similiar scripts. And in FF and Chrome requests waitng each other. So i dont get any reply from apache before first request is completed. Test script with sleep was written only to understand why server works in such manner, but when i find that in ie loading is simulteniously, i dont know where is the problem. By the way when testing it i open 2 tabs and just refresh page one after another, and second page wait completing of first to start loading, and this i can see with timers.

Answer (score 0):

Most servers have limits as for how many connections a single user can have. Another reason your pages could be loading one after another could be session variables. If the files you're using open sessions, the first page will have to fully load, and the session will have to close before the second page will begin to load.

Neither of the above situations would respond differently in different browsers, which leads me to believe the problem is browser specific. If you're trying to load the same page on two tabs, my best guess would be that the version of chrome and firefox you're using send the requests in order, and wait before firing the second.

One last thing that comes to mind is that for AJAX calls, if you're not doing them asynchronously, they will fire in order, but wait of the first to finish. An example would be google analytics. Their tracking code is now asynchronous so that page load times are not hurt. You can read more about Asynchronous JavaScript [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/)

It's normally best to combine AJAX requests to reduce network congestion and server load. If possible I'd recommend you look into combining them, as once your application or website becomes more popular, 10000 requests will always be better than 20000...